# Firing off an Intent Service every X seconds, whats the difference in performance?

Tags: android, service, intentservice, android-handler

I know there are many ways to call a function every x seconds or schedule a job. My question is what is the best fit solution for my problem?

I have a heavy task that I want to run in a background thread (Database queries, making HTTP calls).

For this I use an `IntentService` since it's `onHandleIntent` function runs in a background worker thread and the started services are queued.

The queue doesn't really matter for me since `startService()` will only be called from one place.

Now, I want to start this service frequently, sometehing like 10-15 seconds.

This was my old solution:

```
class MyService extends IntentService {
  @Override
  protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    mutex = new Object();
    while(isServiceRunning) {
      doTheBigJob();
      syncrhonized (mutex) {
        mutex.wait(15000);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I assume this is bad practice.

Now my Intent service only contains `doTheBigJob()`. But how should I time my `startService()` call to make this happen every 15 sec for forever. What is the most optimal way?

This is a KIOSK app so it will always be in the foreground and the user can't escape it.

Comment: If you have to do regular network updates, the best web would be is to use websockets and subscribe to events instead so you only fetch them when there is a need to.

Comment: @GregoryNowik Thanks but the question wasn't about "what networking protocol should I use"